# The category Prob of finite measure spaces does not admit all products

Tags: pr.probability, ct.category-theory, measure-theory

I am currently working in a category called **Prob** which has objects which are finite measure spaces and morphisms which are measure preserving maps between the spaces. A map $f:X\to Y$  is measure preserving if $$f_\#p_X(A) = p_Y(A) $$
for all subsets $A\subseteq Y$. I know that products do not exist in this category but I am having difficulties proving it. I have tried to disprove it with the space $(X,p_X)=(\{1,2\},\frac{1}{2})$ which consists of 2 points with equal probability. I am unable to arrive at a contradiction, even when trying measure preserving maps. Does anyone have an idea on how to disprove this?

Comment: How do you “know” products don’t exist in this category?  If you believe it because you learned it from someone else, can you tell us who they were, and point us to any existing literature on this category?

Comment: Voted to close because the OP was active 12 hours after @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine posted his comment, and chose to ignore it.

Comment: This is a problem I am working on as part of a project. My teacher definitely knows that it does not exist and has told me but he did not say why. I think it is because there are no products in measure spaces generally but I cannot find a proof of that either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP should ask the teacher who is supervising this project

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the way this Questions has been asked. Voted to re-open.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: This question is definitely *not* of research level. Voting to keep closed.

Comment: The way that Questions are Closed here is reminiscent of a primitive theocratic state: it only takes five self-appointed Judges, there's Due Process, opportunuty for Defence (or voting to keep open) or indeed consistent Law. Besides this,  rejecting naive questions from students alienates our future colleagues.

Comment: Should have said "**no** Due Process..."

Comment: Steven Landsburg voted to close the question because the OP had not addressed a well-received comment, which has since been addressed. Yemon Choi voted to close the question for the reason that "the OP should ask the teacher who is supervising this project". I actually encourage my students to seek answers anywhere, including of course sites like MathOverflow (but of course, they must then properly refer to such answers); such search skills do seem to be useful for *re*search.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Alex M. voted "to keep closed", saying that the "question is definitely *not* of research level" -- which is probably right in the sense that answers to such a question cannot be published (I have no expertise in category theory). However, there are a great many questions left open on MathOverflow, some of them even well received, posted by students studying a subject (from a book or otherwise) and having difficulties at some points. For all these reasons, I have voted to re-open.

Comment: I am pretty new to this site so I do not know how things normally go on here but it feels more hostile than twitter. I appreciate the answer I got very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\pr}{\mathsf{Prob}}\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}\newcommand{\tX}{\tilde X}\newcommand{\tx}{\tilde x}\newcommand{\tmu}{\tilde\mu}\newcommand{\tnu}{\tilde\nu}\newcommand{\tpi}{\tilde\pi}\newcommand{\tY}{\tilde Y}\newcommand{\tf}{\tilde f}\newcommand{\tF}{\tilde F}\newcommand{\vpi}{\varphi}\newcommand{\tG}{\tilde G}$
Given a family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of objects (in a category), a [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)#Product_of_an_arbitrary_family) (defined up to an isomorphism) of this family is an object $X$ equipped with a family $(\pi_i)_{i\in I}$ of morphisms $\pi_i\colon X\to X_i$ such that for every object $Y$ and every family $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ of morphisms $f_i\colon Y\to X_i$ there is a unique morphism $f\colon Y\to X$ such that $\pi_i\circ f=f_i$ for all $i\in I$.

Let $((X_i,\mu_i))_{i\in I}$ be a family of objects in the category $\pr$, so that for each $i\in I$ we have that $X_i$ is a finite set and $\mu_i$ is a probability measure over $X_i$.

Suppose that a product $(X,\mu)$ of the family $((X_i,\mu_i))_{i\in I}$ exists in $\pr$, equipped with a family $(\pi_i)_{i\in I}$ of morphisms $\pi_i\colon X\to X_i$ such that for every object $(Y,\nu)$ and every family $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ of morphisms $f_i\colon Y\to X_i$ there is a unique morphism $f\colon Y\to X$ such that $\pi_i\circ f=f_i$ for all $i\in I$.

Probe first the object $(Y,\nu)$ in $\pr$ with $Y=P:=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ and $\nu:=\bigotimes_{i\in I}\mu_i$, and for each $i\in I$ let $f_i:=p_i$, where $p_i(x):=x_i$ for $x=(x_i)_{i\in I}\in P$. Then $f_i$ is a morphism in $\pr$ for each $i\in I$, and hence there is a unique morphism $f\colon Y\to X$ such that
\begin{equation}
    \text{$\pi_i\circ f=p_i$ for all $i\in I$.}\tag{-1}\label{-1}
\end{equation}
If $f(y)=f(z)$ for some $y=(y_i)_{i\in I}$ and $z=(z_i)_{i\in I}$ in $Y=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$, then $y_i=p_i(y)=\pi_i(f(y))=\pi_i(f(z))=p_i(z)=z_i$ for all $i\in I$, so that $y=z$. So, the morphism $f\colon P\to X$ is injective.

So, $X$ can be identified with the union $P\cup Z$ for some finite set $Z$ disjoint from $P$, and then we will have
\begin{equation}
    \text{$\pi_i(x)=p_i(x)=x_i$ for all $x=(x_i)_{i\in I}\in P$;}\tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation}
see details on this at the end of this answer.

Now let $(Y,\nu)$ be any object in $\pr$ such that
for each $i\in I$ there is a morphism $f_i\colon(Y,\nu)\to(X_i,\mu_i)$.
Then there is the unique morphism $f\colon(Y,\nu)\to(X,\mu)$ in $\pr$ such that $\pi_i\circ f=f_i$ for all $i\in I$.

So, for any set $B$ of the form
\begin{equation*}
    B=\prod_{i\in I}B_i \subseteq P,\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
in view of \eqref{0} and the condition $\pi_i\circ f=f_i$ for all $i\in I$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \mu(B)&=(f_{\#}\nu)(B) \\ 
    &=\nu(f^{-1}(B)) \\ 
    &=\nu(\{y\in Y\colon f(y)\in B\}) \\ 
    &=\nu(\{y\in Y\colon \forall i\in I\ f(y)_i\in B_i\}) \\ 
    &=\nu(\{y\in Y\colon \forall i\in I\ \pi_i(f(y))\in B_i\}) \\ 
    &=\nu(\{y\in Y\colon \forall i\in I\ f_i(y)\in B_i\}) \\ 
    &=\nu\Big(\bigcap_{i\in I}\ f_i^{-1}(B_i)\Big)=:H_{(f_i)_{i\in I}}(B).    
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

So, if a product $(X,\mu)$ of the family $((X_i,\mu_i))_{i\in I}$ exists in $\pr$ then, for each $B$ of the form \eqref{1}, $H_{(f_i)_{i\in I}}(B)$ does not depend on the choice of morphisms $f_i\colon(Y,\nu)\to(X_i,\mu_i)$.

---

Let now $I=\{1,2\}$ and $(Y,\nu)=(X_1,\mu_1)=(X_2,\mu_2)=(\{0,1\},U_{\{0,1\}})$, where $U_{\{0,1\}}$ is the uniform probability distribution over the set $\{0,1\}$. Let $B=\{(0,1)\}=B_1\times B_2$, where $B_1:=\{0\}$ and $B_2:=\{1\}$.

Let first $f_1=f_2=\id$, where $\id$ is the identity mapping of the set $\{0,1\}$. Then $f_i\colon(Y,\nu)\to(X_i,\mu_i)$ is a morphism in $\pr$ for each $i\in I=\{1,2\}$. Also, then $\bigcap_{i\in I}\ f_i^{-1}(B_i)=\emptyset$ and hence $H_{(f_i)_{i\in I}}(B)=0$.

Let now $f_1=\id$ and $f_2=\bar\id$, where $\bar\id(j):=1-j$ for $j\in\{0,1\}$. Then again  $f_i\colon(Y,\nu)\to(X_i,\mu_i)$ is a morphism in $\pr$ for each $i\in I=\{1,2\}$. Also, then $\bigcap_{i\in I}\ f_i^{-1}(B_i)=\{0\}$ and hence $H_{(f_i)_{i\in I}}(B)=1/2$.

So, here $H_{(f_i)_{i\in I}}(B)$ depends on the choice of morphisms $f_i\colon(Y,\nu)\to(X_i,\mu_i)$. So, a product of these objects, $(X_1,\mu_1)$ and $(X_2,\mu_2)$, does not exist. $\quad\Box$

---

**Details on \eqref{0}:** Essentially, this is just a relabeling of elements of the set $X$. Here are formal details. Let $X_0:=f(P)$, so that $X_0\subseteq X$. Let $Z$ be any set of the same cardinality as $X\setminus X_0$ such that $Z\cap P=\emptyset$, and let $g\colon Z\to X\setminus X_0$ be any bijection.
Let $\tX:=P\cup Z$. Define the map $h\colon\tX\to X$ by the formula
\begin{equation*} 
h(\tx):=
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    f(\tx)&\text{ if }\tx\in P,\\ 
    g(\tx)&\text{ if }\tx\in Z 
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}
for all $\tx\in\tX$, so that $h(\tx)\in X_0$ if $\tx\in P$ and $h(\tx)\in X\setminus X_0$ if $\tx\in Z$.
So, since $f$ is injective and $g$ is bijective, $h$ is bijective.

So, we **relabel** all $x\in X$ as $\tx:=h^{-1}(x)\in\tX$. Accordingly, we relabel all relations $R$ involving $x\in X$ by the corresponding relations $\tilde R$ involving $\tx\in\tX$.

In particular, we define the measure $\tmu$ over $\tX$ by the condition $\tmu(\{\tx\}):=\mu(\{h(\tx)\})$ for $\tx\in\tX$. Then the object $(\tX,\tmu)$ is isomorphic to $(X,\mu)$, via the isomorphism $h$.

Moreover, for each $i\in I$, to have the commutative diagram involving $\tX$, $X$, and $X_i$ (draw it), we let $\tpi_i\colon \tX\to X_i$ be defined by the formula $\tpi_i:=\pi_i\circ h$. Then, with these $\tpi_i$'s, the object $(\tX,\tmu)$ will also be a product of the family $((X_i,\mu_i))_{i\in I}$ -- cf. the description of the meaning of the phrase ["unique up to canonical isomorphism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)#Definition).

Indeed, let $(\tY,\tnu)$ be an object in $\pr$ and let $(\tf_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of morphisms $\tf_i\colon \tY\to X_i$. Since $(X,\mu)$ is a product of the family $((X_i,\mu_i))_{i\in I}$, there exists a unique morphism $F\colon\tY\to X$ such that $\pi_i\circ F=\tf_i$ for all $i\in I$. Let now $\tF:=h^{-1}\circ F$. Then $\tF\colon\tY\to\tX$ is a morphism such that $\tpi_i\circ\tF=\pi_i\circ F=\tf_i$ for all $i\in I$. Moreover, since $F$ is a unique morphism such that $\pi_i\circ F=\tf_i$ for all $i\in I$, it is easy to see that $\tF$ is a unique morphism such that $\tpi_i\circ\tF=\tf_i$ for all $i\in I$. This confirms that $(\tX,\tmu)$ is a product of the family $((X_i,\mu_i))_{i\in I}$.

Finally, for each $\tx\in P$ and each $i\in I$ we have
$\tpi_i(\tx)=\pi_i(h(\tx))=\pi_i(f(\tx))=p_i(\tx)$ by \eqref{-1}, so that \eqref{0} holds -- for the relabeling $(\tX,\tmu)$ of the product $(X,\mu)$, with the corresponding relabelings $\tpi_i$ of the "projections" $\pi_i$.

Comment: Thank you! I would have never gotten to this answer. So this proof basically amounts to showing that the projections are the usual projections right?

Comment: @wouterfransen : The projections are the usual projections on the "$P$-part" of $P\cup Z=X$. It is easy to see that $\mu(Z)=0$. So, one might say the projections are the usual projections $\mu$-almost everywhere. However, this fact is more or less similar to the fact that the category product in the category of sets is the Cartesian product, with the usual projections. I think the main observation is that $H_{(f_i)_{i\in I}}(B)$ does not depend on the choice of morphisms $f_i\colon(Y,\nu)\to(X_i,\mu_i)$ (if the product exists).

Comment: @wouterfransen : I suggest you address Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine's question on where you learned that the product does not exist by adding an answer to it in your post.

Comment: I'm sorry for being slow on this, it is very difficult to grasp. How does $pi_i(x)=x_i$ for the $x\in P$? I feel like this function could also be for example 1-x, (in the case of the example ({0,1},1/2))

Comment: @wouterfransen : I have added details on this, at the end of the answer. These details are somewhat tedious -- but this is, essentially,  just a relabeling of elements of the set $X$.

Comment: This clarifies it alot thank you so much!

Comment: @wouterfransen : I have added a few more details on this. Let me know **the  first place** where something still seems unclear. Try to be quite specific and precise when asking questions or making mathematical statements -- they should be carefully prepared and reread several times before publishing them. In particular, you should understand that 1-x is not a function (unless x is a function, and it is you who should declare what x is); at best, 1-x or, rather, $1-x$ could be some expression.

Comment: It is very clear now thank you. I learned a lot from the answer you gave me